# When a Thread is destroyed are the variables destroyed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wanted to process elements of Queue by 2 threads and prepare OutputQueue in same order as input. I still have to make some Synchronized blocks but I am stuck with the Following questions.

1. Empty OutputQueue is returned
2. Am I doing this the right way.

**ThreadMailClass.java**

```
public class ThreadMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputQueue={2,3,4,5,6};
        processJobs(inputQueue);
    }

    public static void processJobs(int[] inputQueue){

        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int i:inputQueue){
            queue.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Input Queue Size:" + queue.size());

        HeavyWorkRunnable hr = new HeavyWorkRunnable();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new HeavyWorkRunnable(queue),"t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new HeavyWorkRunnable(queue),"t2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

         try {
             t1.join();
         t2.join();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//This method is returning empty Queue.
        Queue<Integer> outputQueue = hr.getOutputQueue();
        System.out.println("Printing Output Queue.." + outputQueue.size());
        for(Integer i:outputQueue)
            System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println("Printing Done");


    }
```

**HeavyWorkRunnable.java**

```
public class HeavyWorkRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Queue<Integer> outputQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private Queue<Integer> inputQueue;

    public HeavyWorkRunnable() {

       }
    public HeavyWorkRunnable(Queue<Integer> inputQueue) {
        this.inputQueue = inputQueue;
       }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Doing heavy processing - START "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            processInputQueue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Doing heavy processing - END "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    private void processInputQueue() {
        while(inputQueue.peek()!=null){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-->input size -->"+ inputQueue.size());
            outputQueue.add(inputQueue.remove());
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-output size -->"+ outputQueue.size());
        }
    }

    public Queue<Integer> getOutputQueue() {
        return this.outputQueue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `LinkedList` as a queue in multiple threads. It isn't thread-safe, and you aren't using any synchronization to make it so. It won't work properly until you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When a Thread is destroyed are the variables destroyed?

When the `run()` method call terminates, the thread stacks are discarded, and the thread's reference to its `Runnable` is nulled.  By that time all of the `run()` method's local variables will be out of scope.

When the `Runnable` is becomes unreachable it is garbage collected.  The GC is what will ultimately "destroy" the instance variables of the `Runnable`.

---

> Am I doing this the right way.

I would use an `ExecutorService`, and deal with the issue of ordering the outputs by creating a list of `Future` objects returned by the `submit(...)` method.

In your code, you seem to have three distinct instance of `HeavyWorkRunnable` and you seem to be retrieving the output queue from the instance that you *didn't* pass to a thread.  That doesn't look correct to me.  There are also problems with (lack of) synchronization on the shared input queue.  That could lead to race conditions and memory visibility problems.

> Empty OutputQueue is returned

Yes.  That is a consequence of the "three instances" problem above.

Comment: So when I call `hr.getOutputQueue()` , this is returning empty list. Since I am calling this after `t1.join()` I guess the Thread and all the variables of the Thread class are destroyed already. 
How can I get the `outputQueue()` ? Appreciate your inputs on my question.

Comment: No.  It is returning an empty list because you are looking at the wrong list.  See my comment about 3 distinct `HeavyWorkRunnable` instances.